# Incorporate Absolute Truth in Predictive Models

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I am trying to learn a model $V=f(X,Y,Z)+\epsilon$ by looking at a series of observations $(v_1, x_1, y_1, z_1), (v_2, x_2, y_2, z_2) ..., , (v_n, x_n, y_n, z_n)$.

I **know** the true $E(X)$, but because I don't have enough sample data or maybe I was too lucky or unlucky in collecting my samples so that the true $E(X)$ is very different from the empirical $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)$.

My question is how to incorporate my prior knowledge of the absolute truth in the model, so that it does not make assumptions based on empirical $\bar{x}$.

Examples:

1) $X$ is a very slow moving variable. For a long time, it keeps moving up, and then for a long time it keeps moving down. But in the long run, $E(X)=0$. If I only have observations for part of the trend, it looks as if $X$ can only go up/down.

2) Let $X$ be coin tosses. $X=1$ if coin turns head; $X=0$ if coin turns tail. I get an unlucky streak in the observed data, where 70% of the observed data are 1s and 30% are 0s. But I know it is a fair coin and $E(X)=0$.

Comment: If you know the absolute truth, why do you need a model? Thinking about it in a Bayesian context, if you know the exact $E(X)$ with certainty (somehow), your prior would have all the probability concentrated at $E(X)$ and the data and likelihood would have no effect on the posterior distribution.

Comment: How do you know what the true E(X) is?  Can you describe your data more specifically than comparing it to coin tossing?